# converting date object with a known timezone, to current timezone

Tags: java, android, date, timezone

So I'm getting some date objects from a web server, I know that the server has the time in GMT +1 (Berlin), how can I convert the date object, to the current phone timezone date object?

Most of the questions on stackoverflow are only about formatting within a timezone, but not actually converting like this.

I've tried this

```
 Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
    calendar.setTime(timeFromServer);
    Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

WHen I print, calendar2.getTime().toString() and timeFromServer.toString() will be the same;

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @Dan I've updated my question

Comment: What precisely does “some date objects from a web server” mean? Are you getting a string?

Comment: @BalsilBourque it's a string, but with retrofit and gson, it's converted to a date object, the format is like 2017-03-02 18:07:34.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Joda time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) and it works. You can try with Joda time. This method will convert time from server to display format time below and change to the relevant local time

```
public static final String SERVER_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    public static final String DISPLAY_POST_FORMAT = "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy";

public static String convertDateStrToDisplayFormat(String timeFromServer) {
        DateTimeFormatter serverFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Constants.SERVER_FORMAT);
    serverFormatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(timeFromServer, serverFormatter);

    DateTimeFormatter pointTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Constants.POINT_TIME_FORMAT);
    pointTimeFormatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));

    return pointTimeFormatter.print(dateTime)
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to convert to String, what if I only want the date? is there a better way than parsing again string to date? because currently there are a lot of things to do, just to convert between 2 timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to convert the date from the server and convert it to current phone timezone date object

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
SimpleDateFormat deviceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
deviceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date utcDate ;
Date deviceDate ;

utcDate = sourceFormat.parse(event_date);
deviceDate = deviceFormat.parse(utcDate.toString());
```

event_date is a String that has the server date. After this you have your converted Date on deviceDate.

Comment: Well in my case, event_date is already a date object. What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try two things:
`utcDate = sourceFormat.parse(event_date.toString());`
or this `deviceDate = deviceFormat.parse(sourceFormat.format(event_date));` . I think that the first one will work

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Date` does not use timezone, so when you try to print the string representation of the following date objects using method `Date#toString()`, the results are the same:

- `calendar2.getTime().toString()`
- `timeFromServer.toString()`

In order to test the string representation correctly with timezone, you need to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
f.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());

// Date correctly printed with timezone:
System.out.println(f.parse(calendar.getTime()));
```

However, your conversion written in the question is correct, here's how I tested it using JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testDateConversion() throws ParseException {
  String serverText = "2017-03-02T11:54:30.207+01:00";

  SimpleDateFormat serverFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  serverFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
  Date timeFromServer = serverFmt.parse(serverText);

  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
  calendar.setTime(timeFromServer);

  assertEquals(2017, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  assertEquals(Calendar.MARCH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
  assertEquals(2, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  assertEquals(9, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
  assertEquals(54, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  assertEquals(30, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
  assertEquals(207, calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

  SimpleDateFormat currFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  currFmt.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());

  System.out.printf("server_timestamp  = %d, server_date  = '%s', server_str  = '%s'%n",
      timeFromServer.getTime(),
      serverFmt.format(timeFromServer),
      timeFromServer.toString());
  System.out.printf("current_timestamp = %d, current_date = '%s', current_str = '%s'%n",
      calendar.getTime().getTime(),
      currFmt.format(calendar.getTime()),
      calendar.getTime().toString());
}
```

Result:

```
server_timestamp  = 1488452070207, server_date  = '2017-03-02T11:54:30.207+01:00', server_str  = 'Thu Mar 02 11:54:30 CET 2017'
current_timestamp = 1488452070207, current_date = '2017-03-02T09:54:30.207-01:00', current_str = 'Thu Mar 02 11:54:30 CET 2017'
```

See also:

- [SimpleDateFormat (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)